# Auto set time and date column

Tags: oracle10g

I created a table which have following columns.

```
E_id, e_name,e_date,time_in,time_out
```

I want autoupdate `e_date`,`time_in` and `time_out` column when i insert new  values in table.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns? What values should it auto update? You can use DEFAULT clause during table creation.

Comment: You may use trigger to insert / update date in table column on when insert or update row.

Comment: Hi,  data types of colums are:- e_id varchar(4), e_name varchar2(40),e_date date,time_in time ,time_out time.i want e_date ,time_in and time_out to auto update whenevr i insert any value to table.these column to autoget current date and time

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer to give you an example to define default columns for character datatypes...

Answer (score 0):

You can define default values for your columns.
Which values do you need?

For example, if you need the Sysdate:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(...,
INSERT_DATE       DATE      DEFAULT SYSDATE    NOT NULL);
```

or, if you need to update your table structure:

```
ALTER TABLE t
MODIFY (INSERT_DATE       DATE      DEFAULT SYSDATE);
```

You can use SYSTIMESTAMP too, instead of SYSDATE, if you need fractional seconds.

But if you have character fields you can use something like the following:

```
DEFAULT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')   -- Date component
```

or

```
DEFAULT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS')   -- Time component
```

Comment: How to insert values for this datatype

Comment: Using default sysdate it set date with time.but i dnt want time in e_date column.i want time in time_in colum only

Comment: You can't store the time portion only, unless you use a character datatype (VARCHAR2 or CHAR). If you use a DATE, you have the Date and Time (with the precision of the second). And if you use a TIMESTAMP, you can specify fractional seconds too. But if you need the time portion only, you can, just for example, use the VARCHAR2(6) datatype. Using TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS') as the default value, you will have the time portion only in your column, but as a character datatype.